# First read entry in ZipArchive is non-seekable when using ZipArchiveMode.Read?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, zip, .net-8.0

Calling `ZipArchive.Entries[1]` to read the second entry has no such issue.Basically the stream returned by `ZipArchive.Entries[0].Open()` seems to be always a deflate stream that has no seek capabilities?

Is this normal? Or is something else going on?

An `InvalidOperationException` is thrown when I try reading the `Position` property of the first returned entry's stream. Entries that follow have no such issue.

Comment: What do you mean "a deflate stream that has no seek capabilities"? Deflate compressed data is never seekable. Perhaps you could show some code and output to illustrate what you're trying to do, what happened, and what you expected.

Comment: If it would be not seekable you should get a NotSupportedException, If you get a InvalidOperationException you might want to take a closer look at it (Inner Exception for example) if it contains more details about the actual problem.

Comment: After looking at the source of ZipArchive could it be that not all entries are compressed and some are just stored in the Zip? Just stored entries might be seekable.

Comment: Why are you trying to seek it anyway? `Seek` is one of the weirdest features of `Stream`, I'm not sure why it exists on a type that is supposed to be sequential-read only. Just read it all in order

Answer (score 0):

> deflate stream that has no seek capabilities?
>
> Is this normal? Or is something else going on?

This is normal. The returned stream will decompress data as it is read.

Data compression is about reducing redundancies in the data, and this inherently makes seeking very difficult. If you have "1111111000000000" you can replace it with "1709", i.e. repeat "1" 7 times, then repeat "0" nine times. But if I want to know the value for digit ten you need to start at the beginning.

There are some formats specifically designed for semi-random access. Video compression works in "blocks", with an index to keep track of where each block starts. So if you jump to some random time you only need to decompress from the beginning of that block, not from the start of the entire video.

In your case you need to copy the deflate stream to some stream that *do* support seeking, like a memory stream of file stream. Then you can seek as much as you want.